# Multiple neo4j instances configuration

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm wondering how to set up two different neo4j server instances when using Spring Data, e.g. one for test and the other for production purposes. I have my production server instance running on default port (7474) and my test server instance running on port 7475. How can I define where my node/relationships entities should be stored (whether in test or production environment, in this case)? I was not able to find it in the docs. This was my beans file so far, running everything just out the box (when I just used a single neo4j server instance):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <!-- Neo4j -->
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="repositories.neo4j"/>

    <!-- some more stuff -->
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven, also consider maven profiles. Here's a good comparison between spring and maven profiles: [maven profiles or spring profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869064/maven-profiles-or-spring-profiles)

Comment: My question is how? For example, when using Spring Data with MongoDB I can set all Mongo properties in the Mongo template. So, for example, I could define some environment variable (e.g.: -Denvironment=test) that reads a certain property file depending on its value and sets up the mongo template properly. Is there any equivalent when dealing with Neo4j?

Comment: You can do it the same way you did it with MongoDB. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874017/controlling-a-project-with-maven-and-spring-how-to-set-spring-config-file-using how you can use maven profiles to configure spring properties. You probably don't want to configure the Neo4jTemplate, but a GraphDatabaseService instead (like e.g. EmbeddedGraphDatabase)

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from [Spring environment abstraction](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) or [Spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/). They both allow environment-dependent configurations.