# Pass Spring profile in maven build

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am running the spring boot app by passing the spring active profile like below:

```
spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

But how do I pass the spring.profiles.active when creating the package using maven. Following is the maven command:

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: `mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`?

Comment: No that's not working. When I run the war, its saying the profile is not set

Comment: Then you'll need to post some code. Start with the POM.

Comment: You would like to set a system property (-Dspring.profiles.active=dev) at build time using maven so that the property can be used by Spring, correct?

Comment: More information here, https://riptutorial.com/spring-boot/example/31100/set-the-right-spring-profile-by-building-the-application-automatically--maven-

Answer (score 10):

In case someone have the same situation, you can achieve this with 2 steps with spring boot and maven:
First in spring properties or yaml file, add the spring.profiles.active with it's value as placeholder:

`spring.profiles.active=@active.profile@`

Second, pass the value with maven:

`mvn clean install -Dactive.profile=dev`

When the jar/war packaged, the value will be set to dev.

you can also leverage the use of maven profiles:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <active.profile>dev</active.profile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <active.profile>test</active.profile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then run:

```
mvn clean install -Pdev
```

Answer (score 6):

Maven is a build-time tool, the only way to make it modify the eventual runtime behaviour of the built artifact is to use its (*build-time*) profiles. This must not be confused with Spring's *runtime* profiles which are parameters instructing the Spring container to bootstrap application in a specific way.

In other words, the `spring.profiles.active` parameter doesn't get "baked into" the war file by maven, you'll still need to pass it when starting the application up, be it via command-line parameters or configuration file or whatever mechanism your servlet container offers.

Answer (score 1):

For package, you may replace install with package

mvn clean install -P dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables.

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=some,test,profiles
mvn spring-boot:run
```