# How to load the properties based on the environment defined in application.properties in Spring application. NOT with Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring and I'm studying it. And stumbled upon the @Profile annotation.

I want to write a simple project with Spring (not Springboot) to learn how to load properties based on the environment using @profile annotation. Almost everywhere, the examples ([Ex1](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-profiles/), [Ex2](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1)) I see only with the Springboot. I'm wondering whether we cannot write a Spring application that can dynamically load the properties based on the environment (dev, prod).

1. Some examples ( [Ex3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267372/loading-environment-properties-using-spring-profiles), [Ex4](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/), [Ex5](https://springframework.guru/spring-profiles/)) show with the @Profile but those have hardcoded the bean details for each environment like below. Is this how we have to write the property loading?

   ```
   @Profile("dev")
   @Bean
   public String devDBCcnnection() {        
   System.out.println(dbConfiguration.getUrl());    
   return "DB Connection for Dev";
   }

   @Profile("test")
   @Bean
   public String devTestCcnnection() {  
    System.out.println(dbConfiguration.getDriverClassName());
    return "DB Connection for Test";
   }

   @Profile("prod")
   @Bean
   public String devProdCcnnection() {
   System.out.println("DB Connection for Prod");
   return "DB Connection for Prod";
   }
   ```
2. It has to write a bean for each profile like in the above example?

Can someone tell me using @Profiles, can't dynamically load the property values like in Spring applications?

Appreciate it if you can give the samples with Spring 5

Comment: do you have multiple application properties profiles or only one file? If you use one file you can set those properties in your pom (maven) file.

Answer (score 0):

> Almost everywhere, the examples (Ex1, Ex2) I see only with the
> Springboot. I'm wondering whether we cannot write a Spring application
> that can dynamically load the properties based on the environment
> (dev, prod).

Spring boot uses the spring context. The spring context allows you to use profiles. Therefore no problem using profiles with simple Spring project (non spring-boot).

There are many ways that you can use Profiles.

One of them is the example that you gave with specific beans that have `@Profile` and get registered in spring for a specific profile.

Another one, more commonly used in enteprise applications is to ship a jar application with multiple application.yaml files. So for example you ship your application, containing `dev-application.yaml` and `qa-application.yaml`. You can then start your application selecting a specific profile to be active. Then that specific application.yaml will be used when the application starts up to build the spring context. So the aplication will be started with `qa-application.yaml` and will have a connection to the QA database.

But be careful the default application.yaml will also be loaded. The specific application.yaml for example `qa-application.yaml` will be loaded on top of default `application.yaml`.

The following article contains very good information about spring profiles
[spring profiles article](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-profiles/)

Considering my example here, I quotte something relevant from that article.

> The Default Profile The default profile is always active. Spring Boot
> loads all properties in application.yml into the default profile. We
> could rename the configuration file to application-default.yml and it
> would work the same.
>
> Other profiles will always be evaluated on top of the default profile.
> This means that if a property is defined in the default profile, but
> not in the qa profile, the property value will be populated from the
> default profile. This is very handy for defining default values that
> are valid across all profiles.

In order to activate a specific profile

For non spring-boot projects here is a very good answer [spring active profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510494/7237884)

For spring-boot projects you can

1. Use a system variable to start your jar file

   `java -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -jar myApp.jar`
2. Use an environment property to start your jar file

   `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=qa`

   `java -jar myApp.jar`